# How to handle holidays when computing T+2 date

Tags: foreign-exchange

I'm implementing an algorithm that finds the T+2 settlement date for FX transactions (from the trade date). I also got a number of examples from the business analysts to test my algorithm. As far as I'm aware, the T+2 date means the second business day from trade date, so for example if the trade was on 2022-06-16 Thursday, then T+2 is 2022-06-21 Tuesday (the first business day is 2022-06-17 Friday, Saturday and Sundays are not business days, 2022-06-20 Monday is holiday, not business day).

However, according to the examples I received, for 2022-06-17 Friday the T+2 date should be 2022-06-21 Tuesday - according to the business analyst, if settlement is not actually happening on a weekday, it doesn't matter if it's a holiday. This confuses me. I looked up a few T+2 definitions on the internet and they all mention business days, but haven't actually found an example with a holiday as the next weekday after trade date. Is the example I got wrong? Is there a publicly available calculator that computes the T+2 date, so I can verify my calculations?

Comment: trick question for you: which country's holidays would the FX markets use given that they are international

Comment: The trivial answer is to use both (so for a CHF-SEK transaction use the Swiss and Swedish calendars). Unfortunately according to the BAs there should be no FX transactions done at all on US holidays (so no CHF-SEK trade on 4 July). Then there is a thing called "cross currency swap" which potentially involves a financial center in a 3rd country which sets the interest rate (e.g. LIBOR), so there should be no transactions on holidays at that country (in this case, the UK) as well. It's complicated, so for the first step I'd like to be able to count T+2 for a single calendar (then combine them).